# Timeouts when uploading photos

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Anyone else is getting timeouts for photo uploads to the Graph API in the last 4 days? This is really killing my application which is very photo-oriented.

I get these errors in the log when trying to POST to /ALBUM_ID/photos:

```
"CurlException: Failed to create formpost data"
"CurlException: 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104"
"CurlException: Unknown error occured"
```

This didn't happened before this week (I've been running the same code for months and it worked).

Please note that some photos are getting uploaded fine, but very slow (10-20 seconds to small photos). the JS SDK also get those timeouts, and I saw it happens on other apps that upload photos to albums as well.

How can we solve this? I opened a bug but it seems like no one at Facebook is noticing:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/321724724515164

Comment: You've got response from developer on that bug requiring to provide more details and code sample. Here people also prefer samples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*How can we solve this? I opened a bug but it seems like no one at Facebook is noticing*"  It gets solved by Facebook.  So not much we devs here on s/o can do for now other than to add more information to that bug.  I've not been able to reproduce.  More than likely it's a bad server in their cluster, not necessarily bad code.